# Debug C++ DLL called from a C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, dll

**[EDIT]**

**Solution found with PaulF. I hadn't thought to enable debug of native code in the Debug property of the C# project.**

I am working on a C# project which call a C++ DLL with a C wrapper to make the link between the two langages. The C# Project is attached to a processus (a software) and I would like to debug my DLL like I can debug the C# project. When I add breakpoints in my `.cpp` files, the breakpoint is unreachable when I launch the debug with F5.

Moreover, I have post-build events which consist to copy/paste my `.dll` and `.pdb` files of the C# project and C++ DLL in the right folder of the software to be able to use it.

For information, I am loading my native DLL in `NativeImpot.cs` using :

```
public const string DllName = "SampleDll.dll";
public const CallingConvention DllCallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall;

[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr AllocateHandle(int width, int height, int nFrame, string path, string filename);
```

On internet I found a lot of solutions but any works. I am a novice in Visual, and again more concerning Dll.

Here it is an image of my Visual solution :
[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you compile your library with DEBUG flags?

Comment: What do you mean? I compile `SampleDll`and get the `.dll` and `.pdb` files used by the c# plugin of the software. I build the dll each time with right click on `SampleDll`

Comment: When you compile, you have options for RELEASE and DEBUG. DEBUG generates symbols inside your code (the generated file is bigger) to be able to debug it within a debbuger. You must link with the "debug" version of your library.

Comment: In the C# Project Properties -> Debug have you ticked the "Enable native code debugging" box

Comment: @PaulF it was that !!!! The debug is quite slow now but I can reach the breakpoint. Thanks !

Comment: I've now posted that as an answer - you can mark it as correct to help other users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, in a C# project debugging an unmanaged DLL is not enabled, you have to specifically enable it.

In the C# Project Properties -> Debug you need to tick the "Enable native code debugging" box